# Can you export and import templates for multi-site use?

Tags: webforms

Is there a way to take a form built on one site, save it as a template, and use it on another site? Currently all themes and modules are shared so I assumed the Webform Tempaltes would be available on all 3 sites but they are not. Is there a way to do this? This is running on Drupal 8 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's Drupal8 you can:

- save webform as a webform template
- export/import the source file.
  [image] You can copy it and the paste to the new webform on the other site. It will duplicate an identical webform for you.

Comment: @svsdnb You're welcome, glad to help!

Comment: The Export tab is the top right of the above screenshot is an even a better option because you get the entire webform's configuration file which can be imported via  /admin/config/development/configuration/single/import